# Image upload control used and show to image control in mvc 3.0 without save?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

HTML Code

```
<div id="container" title="Choose File">
<div id="doit">
 <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
  <div id="preview_ie">
  hijjjj
   </div>
</div>
<input id="hid" type="file" size=1 onchange="readURL(this);" >
</div>
```

JQuery and add jquery

```
function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new window.FileReader();


            reader.onload = function (e) {

                $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(150)
                        .height(200);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

        }

        console.log(input.value);
        var newPreview = document.getElementById('preview_ie');
    document.getElementById('preview_ie').filter.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").src = input.value;
        document.getElementById('preview_ie').filter.item("DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader").sizingMethod="scale";
        document.getElementById('preview_ie').style.width = "160px";
        document.getElementById('preview_ie').style.height = "120px";
     }
</script>
```

used above code all browser display image but does not show IE9.file upload control is hide this control click open browser image and upload but does not show in IE9